# threading.Event - How set() & is_set() work internally?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, generator

In the below code,

```
import time
import threading, signal

def follow(theFile, shutDown=None):
   theFile.seek(0, 2) 
   while True:
      if shutDown and shutDown.is_set(): break
      line = theFile.readline()
      if line:
         yield line

shutDown = threading.Event()

def sigusr1(signo,frame):
   print("Closing it down")
   shutDown.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,sigusr1)
   lines = follow(open("access-log"), shutDown)
   for line in lines:
      print(line)
```

Does `set()` & `is_set()` internally use priority queue for event handling?

Comment: `is_set()` simply returns a boolean flag which is set by `set()` in an atomic way. What makes you think that any queue or event handling is involved with that?

Comment: @freakish Such event handling can be used among threads. So, What is the shared resource used internally? For one thread to read others..

Comment: Whatever the underlying os has. On posix it is mutex together with conditionals.

Comment: @freakish OK, Is this atomic synchronisation(ex: lock) or conditional synchronisation(ex: counting semaphore), but not event semaphore internally?

Comment: `set()` acquires a lock, which calls `sem_wait` on a POSIX build that uses semaphore-based locks. Locks on Windows builds default to using an emulated condition variable, using a critical section and a semaphore.